# Why am I getting banded stripes in my reflections?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I've been using blender for about a week, so I'm still very much a beginner - I'm trying to make a roll of plastic for my website, I'm having a problem though, in that my reflections are showing strange bands.

I'm aware that I need to increase my render samples (the screenshot is to illustrate the problem), but this doesn't remedy the problem.

Anybody got any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of strange bands in reflections]

[image: Close up of strange bands in reflections]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the shading to smooth from the tool shelf (t). If that doesn't work then check your normals or do recalculate outside for the normals. If that doesn't work either check your model for errors, overlapping faces etc...

Comment: Overlapping faces........you Sir, are a legend. Thank you!